# Ruby w/ Sinatra: Could I have an example of a jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
%a{:href => "/new_game?human_is_first=true", :remote => "true"}
            %span Yes
```

Above is my link. Just wondering how to handle this. I need to be able to execute some javascript. Below is a .js.erb file from back when I using rails.

```
$('.welcome_container').fadeOut(500, function(){
  $( '.shell' ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => "board/board" ) ) %>" );
  $('.board_container').fadeIn(500);
});
```

So, my question is, Once /new_game is called in app.rb, I want to be able to send some javascript to the current page (without leaving the page, and have the partial rendered)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [my answer to your other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857374/ruby-w-sinatra-what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-js-erb-from-rails/4857587#4857587) for a comprehensive setup for sending and receiving HTML partials in a production Sinatra app.

As Sinatra is a nice lightweight framework, you are free (forced?) to come up with your own workflow and code for implementing partials and handling such calls. Instead of my explicit route-per-partial, you might choose to define a single regex-based route that looks up the correct data based on the URL or param passed.

In general, if you want Sinatra to respond to a path, you need to add a route. So:

```
get "/new_game" do
  # This block should return a string, either directly,
  # by calling haml(:foo), erb(:foo), or such to render a template,
  # or perhaps by calling ...to_json on some object.
end
```

If you want to return a partial without a layout and you're using a view, be sure to pass `layout:false` as an option to the helper. For example:

```
get "/new_game" do
  # Will render views/new_game.erb to a string
  erb :new_game, :layout => false
end
```

If you want to return a JSON response, you should set the appropriate header data:

```
get "/new_game" do
  content_type :json
  { :foo => "bar" }.to_json
end
```

If you really want to return raw JavaScript code from your handler and then execute that...well, here's how you return the JS:

```
get "/new_game" do
  content_type 'text/javascript'
  # Turns views/new_game.erb into a string
  erb :new_game, :layout => false
end
```

It's up to you to receive the JS and *shudder* `eval()` it.